# Tinymce: allow userdefined tags

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Tinymce is removing unknown tags. I want to use userdefined tags, but I did not find the allowed Tags and their rules defined in Tinymce 4 to adjust it?
I want insert my own tags with the function: tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.create, so tiny adds and accept it like the mark-Tag:

```
<mark>Mytext</mark>
```

so it should look like this

```
<user-tag>Mytext</user-tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a closer look into the documentation.
Try [custom_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acustom_elements).

Comment: I never find what i look for in the documentation. Maybe because my language is not english. But thanks for leading me to this issue - it is what I was looking for!

Comment: it is sometimes difficult to find what one is looking for in the tinymce docs